# Size JDialog so correct size when invisible components made visible

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I have a JDialog that contains a large number of options and it was all working fine, however I have changed it so that by default some options are non visible until the unless the user clicks on the *Show Advanced* button.

When they they do this the options are displayed but because the dialog is not tall enough since it was sized based on those options being hidden a vertical scrollbar is added.

I want the dialog to be sized so large enough for when the advanced options are enabled. I have attempted this by creating the dialog with the advanced option displayed, calling pack() to fit based on advanced options being visible

```
 this.pack();
 showAdvancedAction.actionPerformed(null);
```

and then afterwards calling method to make advanced options invisble.

But still when diplayed the dialog is only large enough for when the options are not shown so when click on *Show Advanced* the dialog adds scroll bar again.

How can I resolve this.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

```
this.pack();
showAdvancedAction.actionPerformed(null);
```

You have the order reversed. You need to pack the frame AFTER the components have been made visible.

```
showAdvancedAction.actionPerformed(null);
this.pack();
```

Comment: Sorry ive confused you I default the code so they are displayed, then I run pack(), then i call showAdvancedAction to make invisible again (every time you call it does the opposite), and then the dialog is made visible

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. The simple answer is that The pack() needs to be called AFTER the visibility of the components is changed. Or you need to invoke `revalidate()` on the panel containing the components so the preferred size can be recalculated. I can't guess what your code is doing. Post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Its simple I iniatlize the dialog to show advanced options, then i call pack(), then I set the visibility of components to false. This should work shouldn't it ?

Comment: I've explained twice why it won't work. So something is not simple. Either 1) you don't understand my suggestion or 2) I don't understand your explanation. If the concept is so simple why can't you post a 20 line [mcve] that demonstrates the problem???

Answer (score -1):

In java swing you can add buttons or components over the panel. but when you try to resize these then you need to use Grid Layout/ GridLayout class. Try using Grid Layouts and arrange your controls by providing X, Y  co-ordinate values. It will definitely work.